# Find and replace using regular expressions or wildcards in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This is in Visual Studio 2010 IDE.

I need to remove the quotes from the following case statements and make them numeric

before:

```
            case "8207":
            case "8208":
            case "8221":
            case "8227":
            case "8291":
```

after:

```
                case 8207:
                case 8208:
                case 8221:
                case 8227:
                case 8291:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS has regex support on the Find and Replace dialog, although the syntax is a little different (you can use the > arrows next to Find and Replace to learn more):
[image: sample]

Answer (score 2):

Replace `"` with an empty string.

If there may be quotes in the case blocks, you can replace `case "` with `case` and `":` with `:`.

If there are strings in the case blocks that end in `:`, replace `case "{:z}":`  with `case \1:`.